# Best way for passing data between components in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What would be the best way to access data between 2 different components?

The use case: on component 1, a user clicks a button, and a random number is generated and stored to variable: `data_out`. To keep the example simple, I am not including a method that is generating the random number. Now, on component 2, I would like to dynamically capture this number `(data_out variable)`, where I am building a data table to show each number.

```
export default {
  name: 'DatatablePage',
    data() {
        return {
           data_out: '123'
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are the components related? Are they parent / child? Siblings? Totally unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

There are typically three ways to handle this based on your component hierarchy and if you're happy to use state management (eg Vuex) or not.

#### Parent / child

Child components *emit* events up to their parent

```html
<!-- parent -->
<template>
  <Child @random-number-generated="captureRandomNumber"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ numbers: [] }),
  methods: {
    captureRandomNumber (num) {
      this.numbers.push(num)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- child -->
<template>
  <button type="button" @click="$emit('random-number-generated', Math.random())">
    Generate random number
  </button>
</template>
```

#### Siblings

Very similar to the parent / child communication, you can use the parent of sibling components to coordinate data by listening for events on some children and passing props or calling methods on others

```html
<!-- parent -->
<template>
  <Child1 @some-event="handleEvent"/>
  <Child2 :prop-name="values"/>
  <Child3 ref="child3"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ values: [] }),
  methods: {
    handleEvent (payload) {
      this.values.push(payload) // will reactively update the Child2 "propName" value
      this.$refs.child3.someMethod(payload) // call a method on Child3
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### [Event Bus](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus)

This can be used if your components are not hierarchically related. You can either create a new `Vue` instance to act as an event bus or use the `$root` instance.

Publishing events works via `$emit`

```js
// event bus
EventBus.$emit('event-name', payload)

// root instance
this.$root.$emit('event-name', payload)
```

and subscribing to events works via `$on`

```js
// event bus
EventBus.$on('event-name', handlerFunction)

// root instance
this.$root.$on('event-name', handlerFunction)
```

#### Store

Lastly, there's a centrally managed state in the form of a [Vuex Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) where data is altered by components *committing* [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) (synchronous) or *dispatching* [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) (asynchronous) and subscribers react to changes by mapping to [*state*](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) or [*getters*](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

Components need only be under the same root `Vue` instance. There are no other requirements on their relationship.